# Define HTML once for backend and frontend view (PHP, Backbone)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, backbone.js

I have an app. I want it to be able to load the content without relying entirely on JavaScript. However, I have some pages where I want to automatically refresh the data without doing a page reload. I plan to do this using ajax (json) and backbone/underscore templates. The problem is I don't want to have to write the same HTML twice - once in the back-end templates/views (for page reloads, to support non-JS too) and again in the front-end templates. I know I could request just the HTML partial from the server using AJAX, but I'd rather only request JSON. I want to keep bandwidth to a minimum and even HTML stripped of any JavaScript and/or styling is still too much redundant data (tags, white-space etc).

One idea was if there is a template engine that uses the same syntax as a PHP template but I don't know if this exists. I'd be keep to hear how people tend to handle this, or should I just resort to writing the same HTML in two places? Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a PHP port of underscore.js: ["Underscore.php, a PHP port of the functions that are applicable in both languages. Includes OOP-wrapping and chaining."](http://underscorejs.org#links). You might move your templates into text files and load the templates from there. I recommend using [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/) with the [text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) (you can then put all your templates into a folder, define a "package" and easily refer to them from Backbone.js and PHP). You probably will use a build tool that prepares a nice runtime dir.structure

Comment: If you're not familar with RequireJs: don't miss [r.js, a Javascript packager that will minify you modules into one file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js)

Answer (score 1):

You say you only want to request JSON from the server. How are you intending on passing your template to your JS? Presumably you will need to pass the template to the client during the initial page load.

If so, then I would recommend that you use JS to render this template on page load, as well as when the page is refreshed rather than using PHP for the page load and then JS thereafter.

You can have PHP render a container element for your template and then have your JS populate this container with the rendered template, when the DOM is ready.